# В NetBeans при создании файла не работает кнопка обзор

Tags: netbeans

Хочу создать .html не в проекте а просто в каталоге жму  меню->создать файл-> прочее-> файл html-> далее-> даю имя -> хочу задать путь к каталогу а кнопка Обзор не пашет.

Comment: А какой путь до файла пишется ниже в `Created File`? Может быть нет прав на этот каталог?